# Build with F7 Shortcut not available (VS 2012)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I was using <kbd>F7</kbd> to build with vs2008, vs2010, vs2012 but i got a notebook with a german vs 2012 distribution, where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is the default build shortcut rather than <kbd>F7</kbd>.

On some Editors <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is Build, is it maybe the reason, that Microsoft is trying to make their app more universal?

Comment: It's sad that for some it's easier to find StackOverflow then Keyboard Shortcuts in VS. You can customize keyboard shortcuts however you see fit in there.

Comment: Please don't come with "you can customize". In the default installation i am expecting that things are common in any distribution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have been asked what keyboard binding you want to use at the first use of Visual Studio. `F7` is still available if you answer "C++". If you've chosen the default setting, you have Ctrl-Shift-B as Build command.

You can change the key binding in the menu: Tools/Options -> Environment/Keyboard.

With all that configuration possible in that dialog Microsoft is trying to make their app more flexible and configurable.

Comment: Thanks Harper, it's good to know that the default setting is ctrl-shift-b

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your answer still works in VS2017. :-)